# jQuery ajax request returning 405 ( POST not allowed) in laravel app

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to figure this out. Is this an apache configuration? I've seen some filters.php configurations to add POST but if this was the problem it would be somewhere in laravel docs, right?

Routes:

```
Route::get('orders/add', 'OrderController@add');
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
```

Controller (REST methods are empty):

```
class OrderController extends \BaseController {
   public function add()
    {
       if (Request::ajax())
           return "ajax request ";
       else 
           return "not ajax";
    }
...
```

jQuery:

```
function add()
{
   var tid = $('#sites input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id');

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'add',
      data: { tid: tid }
   }).done( function (msg){
      alert(msg);
   });
}
```

Button to send:

```
<button onclick="add()" id="formSubmit"> Carrinho </button>
```

And the error firefox shows me on console when I click the button:

```
POST http://localhost/orders/add [HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed 17ms]
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Route::get` expects a GET HTTP header. U'll need to use `Route::post`.

Instead of

`Route::get('orders/add', 'OrderController@add');`

you should use

`Route::post('orders/add', 'OrderController@add');`

[Source: Laravel routing documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: And I always wondered why the function name was called "get". Well, I'm embarassed. Thanks.

Comment: We all start somewhere :). If you wish to use RESTFUL logic, may i suggest using [RESTFUL controllers](http://daylerees.com/codebright/controllers) (search restful on the page)?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need a /add route if you are using a resource controller as it has a create method on it already.

```
OrdersController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {} // show ALL orders
    public function create() {} // show the form to create an order aka "add"
    public function store() {} // get input from post.
    public function update($order_id) {} // update an order resource 
    public function destroy($order_id) {} // destroy an order resource
}
```

In your ajax change the url to `url: {{URL::route('orders.store')}},` and that should fix it.